# Add resizeWindow in this javascript-jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, window-resize

I need to add the capability to change the return if window is resized. I don't know how to do it.

```
  $scope.widthLessParameter = function(parametro){
      if(!isNaN(parametro)){
        return $(window).width() - parametro + 'px';
      }else{
        return $(window).width() - $(parametro).width() + 'px';
      }
  }
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The question is not clear

Answer (score 1):

You can listen to resize event changes.

```
angular.element($window).bind('resize', function () {
  console.log('window resized');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Call this function from your HTML

like

```
<body onresize="widthLessParameter(parametro value)">
```